# Extracting different-sized elements from a list within a loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a set of 94 lists, each with a different number of elements, and each element of a different length. An example from one of the lists is shown below

```
 > head(output)
 $clusters
 $clusters[[1]]
 [1] "cookie" "duckie" "seven"  "sticky"

 $clusters[[2]]
  [1] "a"      "ah"     "ball"   "blue"   "boo"    "boy"    "bunny"  "bye"    "eight"  "eye"    
 "five"   "go"     "goose"  "he's"   "hello"  "hey"    "hi"     "is"     "it"     "it's"   "leaf"   
 "meow"   "moon"   "no"    
 [25] "oh"     "one"    "ooh"    "pop"    "shh"    "six"    "that"   "this"   "towel"  "two"    
 "uhoh"   "wee"    "what"   "what's" "whoa"   "wow"    "yay"    "yellow" "yes"   


 $edges
 [1] 44 45
```

I'm creating a loop that extracts parts of the list - in the example shown above, I would want to extract `clusters[[1]]` and `clusters[[2]]`.

I've got as far as the following code:

```
   for (i in length(output)) {  
     values <- output[[1]][i]
         }
```

But this only returns the second element, `clusters[[2]]`. What I would like to do is to save the elements from each list as separate dataframes, as in the following examples:

```
 library(tibble)

 values1 <- tribble(~V1,
           "cookie",
           "duckie",
           "seven",
           "sticky") 

 values2 <- tribble(~V1,
           "a",
           "ah",
           "ball",
           "blue",
           "boo",
           "boy",
           "bunny",
           "etc")
```

How can I do this so that I can quickly run it through 94 different-sized lists?

Comment: Isn't `length(output)` just a number and you need `1:length(output)` instead?

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it concatenates the two element in `output` to one dataframe. What I want to do is create a separate dataframe for each element. I've edited the question to show this more clearly.

Comment: What do you want to do with the separate data frame?
Assign it? Save it?
Work with it within the loop?

Comment: This loop is part of a bigger script that uses `lapply()` to run a function through my data. Once I've got my set of dataframes I want to use them within the function to create a large dataset that incorporates info from each of the 94 lists.

Comment: That actually sounds like you need a list of data frames.
In this case there is no need for `for` at all.

`lapply(output$clusters, function(cl)data.frame(V1 = cl, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))` would do the trick.

Comment: This works, thank you! One final query is whether it's possible to name the individual dataframes so they can be identified later, rather than as `df[[1]]`, etc, since each of the 94 lists will generate a `df[[1]]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work on a one-column data frame for each entry of cluster, you can go like this:

```
for (cluster_number in seq_along(output$clusters)) {
  current_cluster_df <- data.frame(
    V1 = output$clusters[[cluster_number]],
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  # Do whatever you want with the data frame
}
```

The key here is accessing `output$cluster[i]` for all valid indices.
`seq_along(list)` will return a vector of these valid indices (think a more robust version of `1:length(list)`).

Your original code has two issues: 1. `length(output)` is not `length(output$clusters)` and 2. you use `for (i in length(output))`. That's a for loop where `i` only loops through one value, namely `length(output)` which happens to be 2, which by chance is also a valid index into `output$clusters`.